# Desktop monitors keep waking after being set to go blank

Tags: multiple-monitors, amdgpu

I just put together a new desktop and I'm using an AMD Radeon RX 590 Series card.

In Settings-> Power I set my displays to go blank after a certain period of time.  For example, lets say I set my monitors to go blank after 5 minutes.  Indeed, after 5 minutes of inactivity, my displays will go blank/dark.  However, after a few seconds, my displays will 'wake up' and the lock screen will be visible.  A few seconds pass and the displays will begin to go blank/dark again but will ultimately 'wake up' to the lock screen after a few more seconds.  This process repeats over and over with no end.

This happened with both 18.04 and 19.10.  I'm using whatever drivers are installed with a normal Ubuntu install...nothing proprietary.

Any idea what might be wrong or how I could resolve?

In the past I've seen this weird behavior before with a failing mouse or keyboard but even when i remove the USB dongle for these devices, my monitors still 'wake up' after going blank.

Comment: I am having the exact problem on a notebook with NVIDIA card.

Answer (score 0):

This might be less of an answer and more of a work around but I found that switching to Wayland resolved this issue for me